# POR QUE WEB API XAMARIN FORMS FUNCIONA EN ANDROID Y NO EN IOS

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

alguna ayuda estoy pasando un objeto con datos a un servicio WebApi del metodo UPDATE, cuando copilo en Android funciona correctamente pero cuando la copilo en IOS el campo de PER_ALTURA y PER_ESTADO pasan con null pero no sale ningun error en su asignacion... tal vez alguien qme ayude.. Gracias
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: prueba a modificar en el info.plist la NSAppTransportSecurity. Establece la NSAllowsArbitraryLoads a true